# How to use laravel auth?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Good day. I'm trying to use laravel `auth` . But i'm bit confused.

I'm already Login and Register.

Here is my login process

```
public function index(){

   if(!Auth::check()){
        return view::make("Login");
     }else{
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
    function loginproses(Request $request){
        extract(Maincontroller::populateform());    
         $a = Loginmodel::where('username',$username)
                    ->where('password',md5($password))
                    ->first();
            if($a === NULL){ 
                return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Username atau Password salah');
            }else{

            $userdata = array(
                    'username' =>$username
                );

           if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){
                return redirect('/');
           }
        }
    }
```

I'm using `Userlogin` as my table so i change this

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Loginmodel::class,
            'table' => 'Userlogin'
        ],
```

but the problem after the login. I get this error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\Loginmodel given, called in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\sitestarter\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php
>   on line 380 and defined

how can i fix it ?

when using google for searching `how to login in laravel` i always see `Laravel auth`. Then do i really need to use `Laravel Auth` ? and do really need to use the auth controller ?

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Loginmodel extend Authenticatable like

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loginmodel extends Authenticatable
{
}

Comment: the error is gone now. but why my login always wrong?